# What does this screw on the Kodak No1a Series III do?

Tags: tilt-shift

I picked up a really damaged Kodak No1a Series III Autographic.

After a couple of hours cleaning it up, its vital organs are working, so I will keep on cleaning it and someday soon I hope, use it with fresh film.

On the front plate, where the lens is, there is a screw knob that makes the front plate move up or down:

[image]

Unfortunately for me, I haven't found a single trace of this feature online yet. No user guides, no pictures of this exact model, and sadly, the camera's design itself doesn't include markings to make sense of it.

Tilt-shift feature? Alignment? Focussing help?

**Has anyone used this plate-moving feature before? If yes, on which camera was it? (Maybe I can find a user guide for a camera with a similar feature), are there samples I can see somewhere?**

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question… If that leather is even slightly stiff, which I'd expect after a century, then look at Pecard Antique leather dressing to get some suppleness & life back in it. I found it for reasons totally unrelated to photography [rescuing WWII flying jackets;) Hard to get outside the US, I had to import mine. Takes a few weeks [literally] to do the job, but results can be stunning.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks! I don’t mind that it’s unrelated, it’s helpful!

Comment: @Tetsujin I looked it up, might be useful sometime for some pieces I have but for this camera, it won’t do. I need to replace the bellows and the outside leathers for it (I poster another question about that yesterday actually).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the "rising front" feature of the No. 1A Series III.

You can think of it as the "shift" part of a tilt/shift lens, except that it only works in one direction. As these cameras were primarily designed to be used vertically, this feature would mostly be used for keystoning correction when shooting buildings and so on - you can keep the camera pointed horizontally so that vertical lines remain vertical, and use the rising front to "point the camera up", so to speak. The lens is centred, more or less, when the pointer (the centre of the two semicircular scoops) is aligned with the engraved line on the board behind it.

You might find [this Kodak brochure](https://www.pacificrimcamera.com/rl/00145/00145.pdf) from the period useful.

Comment: Great find! It a nice old document, I love it. But it’s more of a catalog where they just hover over features of various products rather than a manual for this model. Great find anyways, marking this as solved.

Comment: @MicroMachine - Because the No. 1A was a roll film camera with just a bright finder, the operation of the rising front is necessarily a "by guess and by golly" feature. Unless you have a ground glass or a reflex finder, your only path to accurate framing is experience.

Comment: Yes. I've made some tests with a ground glass but since that was indoors I couldn't really see a big difference.